# How do I fix unexpected end of file error?

Tags: php, cookies, syntax-error

I keep getting this error:

> [19-Nov-2017 06:58:12 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) in /home/aussieug/public_html/ppyazi/cookie/cookielogger.php on line 14

Here is my code:

> https://ghostbin.com/paste/p3ha8

Comment: In the future post the code here, not on external sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply this error arise when you missed something like `"`, `'`, `{`, `}`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, etc. in  your code.

You missed `"` in `header()`

change

```
header ("Location: http://ppyazi.com/index.php);
```

to

```
header ("Location: http://ppyazi.com/index.php");
```